# Why does Luke let Darth Vader kill the Emperor?

Tags: character, star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

I read some articles/books talking about how the Jedi in Star Wars follow similar practices as buddhism. In Return of the Jedi, Luke did not want to fight Vader, but starts fighting once Vader says he will try to turn Leia to the dark side. After cutting off his hand, he decides not to kill him out of compassion

However, if Jedi are supposed to be compassionate and have to see the good in others, how come Luke doesn't try to stop Vader from killing the emperor and instead try to see the good in him also? Also, the sequels/prequels constantly show the Jedi killing other monsters and villains. Why don't they try to see the good in them as well? For example, Darth Maul.

Answer (score 10):

Luke wasn't exactly in a position to stop Vader from killing Palpatine. Remember, he was being attacked by Force Lightning at the time, and Vader picked up Palpatine and threw him in a shaft in the space of about two seconds. There wouldn't have been time for Luke to recover and react even if he had wanted to.

> Also, the sequels/prequels constantly show the Jedi killing other monsters and villains. Why don't they try to see the good in them as well? For example, Darth Maul.

When Darth Maul blocked the path of a heavily-armed group of soldiers, Qui-Gon sent them away so that he and Obi-Wan could deal with Maul. They could have just opened fire on him, but they didn't. Sometimes even Jedi are forced into fighting to defend themselves or the Republic.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think Jedi are trained to see the good in "everyone."  Luke spares Vader because he is Luke's father, and Vader is very conflicted between the light and the dark side.  So, Luke does feel the good in him.  I doubt Luke, or anyone, felt any good within the emperor.

Luke momentarily looses his temper during his bout with Vader, but after he cuts off Vader's hand, Luke regains his composure. And tosses his light saber.

Answer (score 2):

Luke was in a pretty bad way by that point. Quoting directly from the [original script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html), he was "almost unconscious" and alternate passing out and writhing in pain.

Since he was barely able to remain awake, it seems unlikely he could have prevented Vader from doing *anything*:

> Luke is almost unconscious beneath the continuing assault of the 
>   Emperor's lightning. He clutches a canister to keep from falling into 
>   the bottomless shaft as the bolts tear through him.
>
> **EMPEROR:** *Your feeble skills are no match for the power of the dark side. You  have paid the price for your lack of vision.*
>
> Luke writhes on the floor in unbearable pain, reaching weakly up
>   toward  where Vader stands watching.
>
> **LUKE** (groans): *Father, please. Help me.*
>
> Again Vader stands, watching Luke. He looks at his master, the
>   Emperor,  then back to Luke on the floor.
>
> **EMPEROR:** *Now, young Skywalker...you will die.*
>
> Although it would not have seemed possible, the outpouring of bolts 
>   from the Emperor's fingers actually increases in intensity, the sound 
>   screaming through the room. Luke's body writhes in pain.
>
> Vader grabs the Emperor from behind...